# How to Change the selected value to another object value in angular dropdown List

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the example here http://plnkr.co/edit/E3M49KYnzXHYUeKfjNIV?p=preview and what i want is when i select United state from the dropdown list i want to replace it with US in the same dropdown box

How can i implement this with ng-change or ng-blur.

```
<p><strong>Using ng-option directive</strong></p>
<span>Country:</span>
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="country.name for country in countries track by country.code">
    <option value="">-- Select a Country --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So you want to change what is displayed in the dropdown? Your model `country` allready contains `US` if you select `United States`, right?

Comment: Yes, like if i select United States and get US in the dropdown @jamjamg

Comment: its too much wierd.Why u not showing then US itself  rather than full name?

Comment: @R.J because not many people know all the country code. This way it is more readable and user friendly.

Comment: @Builda - but if you change the country code on the fly after selecting the name, it would be confusing for user who don't know the code for that country and might think its an error, maybe you could display "Country Code - Country Name"

Comment: @Builda  but you are hiding the actual contect what user seen and showing somethings else.